# Is there a way to create field collection table dropbox for added content in form

Tags: 7, entities

Im creating a form in content type form format
I will enable public users to create content type for this form.

I have integrated a field collection module within this form like
adding multiple participants

The fields in the field collection contain fields for name, address, contact info, etc..
The user can add as many participants they want in the field collection.

My question is:
Whenever i try to click the button "add another Item" the whole field collection form stacks up in the page. So when I add 10 participants it will make the page longer and difficult to navigate.

What im thnking is, is there a way that i can create a table that contains the added info (displaying limited fields only) when I click the add another item.

similr to hierarchical [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) dropbox function if you are familiar with this

Is there a module that performs similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

There's the [field collection table](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_table) module which provides a table-based widget and formatter for field collection fields.

It's not the same as the hierarchical select Dropbox but its worth a look, and would probably serve as a good place to start if you're thinking about coding your own solution.